# How to efficiently store html diffs

Tags: javascript, html, git, diff

I'd like to make snapshots of a rendered version of my website where I would efficiently only store differences between versions.

Think Git: I'd like to automate checking whether my rendition is different from day to day, and if so, instead of storing the DOM of the new day, just store the difference between old/new version.

E.g. some `div` might have moved relative position, some content might have changed etc.

Is there any way to do just that besides git (or is git the way)? I'd only care for something like "git commit", and the ability to go back to a certain revision. Other than that, speed and efficiency should be most important. Also, I hope there is some method particularly well tailored to XML/HTML structure changes, but I guess that might be too much too ask

Comment: Just curious, why not use `git`? Or unix `diff`?

Comment: What is it that changes the rendering of a particular page? I ask because you say you need the ability to 'go back to a certain revision'; would you have to rollback a database (or something similar) to do that?

Comment: It's just that I would like to see how my website changes, be able to count its div elements, stuff like that. See how it changes over time and plot it. I assume it might get very big, that's why I'd only like to save the specific altered states.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to store/utilize the DOM and differences in the DOM can be found with [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/). They use a **Virtual DOM** to abstract away the DOM.  There are also other [Virtual DOM](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=virtual+dom) implementations.